# JSONP ajax call giving errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to make an AJAX call to this address https://uthsc.edu/faculty/com-myutdoc.php

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://uthsc.edu/faculty/com-myutdoc.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (response) {
        debugger;
        console.log(response); // server response
    },

    error: function(a, b, c) {
        alert("FAILED.");
    }
});
```

I'm getting a jquery was not called error. Any idea why?

Comment: a "jquery was not called" error? What *exactly* is the error? When is it reported?

Comment: Also that URL returns JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: jQuery22303227004583424107_1462370614403 was not called at function.n.extend.error (...)

Reported when the ajax call responds with an error.

Comment: I think that's caused by the fact that the returned content doesn't work as JSONP. A JSONP response should look like a function call; that site returns plain JSON.

Comment: When changed to json datatype: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:54090' is therefore not allowed access.

$.ajax({
        url: "https://uthsc.edu/faculty/com-myutdoc.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        (etc...)

Comment: Right. If you don't have control over that website, then your only choice is to implement a proxy so that you can fetch the content from your *server*. The browser won't allow access from your page loaded from a different domain than that site's.

Answer (score 0):

It come up with error because you make AJAX request to diffirent URL, I think. If you wanna make AJAX request to diffirent URL, your return data should be JSONP, so you won't see error anymore!. 
Take a look as JSONP!